# How do I create a similarity matrix from a similarity data frame?

Tags: r, matrix

I found this online and used this with my data:

```
df <- data.frame(seasons = c("Season1","Season2","Season3","Season4"))
for(i in unique(df$seasons)) {
  df[[paste0(i)]] <- ifelse(df$seasons==i,1,0)
}
```

The only challenge is where there is a 0 in the resultant cell, I want to fill in a meaningful value from a data frame that has data arranged like so:

| S1 | S2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Season1 | Season2 | 3 |
| Season3 | Season1 | 5 |
| Season2 | Season3 | 4 |

Note how a season in a pair could pop up at S1 or S2.

I'll need to fill for example,{row Season1; col Season 2} as well as {col Season 1 and row Season 2} in my matrix as 3.

Is there anyway for me to do this? I tried a few things but decided to give a shoutout to the community in case there is something simple out there I'm missing!

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: We dont understand your question. What do you have and what do you want?

Comment: Hi!I have a similarity data frame (item 1, item 2, similarity) - need too convert it to a similarity matrix that has no empty cells. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Can ouy show your expected outcome please -- is it `xtabs(Value ~ S1 + S2, data=dat)`?

Comment: Think IRTFM got to what I was trying to do - thanks much for checkin-in!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three steps and decided to rebuild the original matrix and call it S:

```
# Make square matrix of zeros
rc <- length(unique(df[[1]]) ) # going to assume that number of unique values is same in both cols
S <- diag(1, rc,rc)

# Label rows and cols
dimnames(S) <- list( sort(unique(df[[1]])), sort( unique(df[[2]])) )

# Assign value to matrix positions based on values of df[[3]]

S[ data.matrix( df[1:2])  ] <-   # using 2 col matrix indexing
    df[[3]]

# -------
> S
        Season1 Season2 Season3
Season1       1       3       0
Season2       0       1       4
Season3       5       0       1
```

It's now a real matrix rather than a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks this is awesome! Is there anyway I can replace the zeros here with relevant numbers such that {Season 1: Season 2} is 3 and {Season 2: Season 1} is also 3?

Comment: You can update that object, say with a new dataframe used in a similar manner: `DF2 <- read.table(text="Season1 Season2 3\nSeason2 Season1  3" )`